# Calculating the two x coordinates at edge of circle for a specific y coordinate

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

How do I find the two opposite x coordinates at the edge of a circle for a specific y coordinate?

A y coordinate of zero means the center of the circle so the two x coordinates would be +- radius

A y coordinate equaling the radius would give two x coordinates of zero.

I'm using Javascript but any language solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about circle placed at `(0,0)` (described by equation `x²+y²=R²`) and you need to return pair of (symmetric) `x` coordinates based on `y` and `R`, that would be something, like:

```
const getX = (y, R) => [1, -1].map(n => n*(R**2-y**2)**0.5)
```

Following is a quick proof-of-a-concept live-demo:

```js
const getX = (y, R) => [1, -1].map(n => n*(R**2-y**2)**0.5)

console.log(getX(0,1))
console.log(getX(1,1))
console.log(getX(-1,1))
console.log(getX(0.7071,1))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

If arbitrary circle center (`(x0,y0)`) is considered (`(x-x0)²+(y-y0)²=R²`), more generic solution should work:

```
const getX = (y, R, x0, y0) => [1, -1].map(n => n*(R**2-(y-y0)**2)**0.5+x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer though technically correct is hugely inefficient. The pattern used creates 2 Arrays every call, and repeats the full calculation twice even though the second result is a simple negative of the first (2 rather than 1 square root operations).

The following is 14 times (1400%) faster

```
const circleXForY = (y, r) => [y = (1 - (y / r) ** 2) ** 0.5 * r, -y];
```

If you include the fact that the result can also be `NaN` when `y > r` then the above function is a staggering 196 times (19,600%) quicker when `y > r || y < -r`.

A further slight improvement is to just use the positive result

```
const circleXForY = (y, r) => (1 - (y / r) ** 2) ** 0.5 * r;
```

The reason I posted a faster version is that this function is very often used when scanning lining circles for graphical like content presentation. I such cases performance is critical.